# obtener valores de una vista en el controlador

Tags: html, laravel

tengo en mi vista una tabla simple que lleno con datos desde la base de datos, para pintar la tabla con los registros utilizo un foreach basico y funciona bien, tengo los registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que necesito obtener el listado de los productos de la tabla con sus valores, es decir recuperar las filas de la tabla con sus valores pero no me resulta, se que debria recibirlos como un array pero aunque coloque los inputs como array ([]) no lo logro...

Como se ve en la imagen al hacer un dd del request solo obtengo la ultima fila de los registros(cantidad 25,  total_producto 37500 y neto_producto 1500)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de la vista donde esta la tabla lo tengo asi:

```
 <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                        <thead >
                            <tr>
                            <th style="width:25%">Producto</th>
                            <th >SKU</th>
                            <th>Cantidad Solicitada</th>
                            <th>Valor Unitario</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot></tfoot>
                        <tbody  id="productos">
                        @foreach($detallePedido as $detalle)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$detalle->producto_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$detalle->nombre_producto}}</td>
                            <td>{{$detalle->sku}}</td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="cantidad_producto form-control" id="cantidad_productos" name="cantidad_productos" value="{{$detalle->cantidad}}" /> </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="valor_neto form-control" id="neto_producto" name="neto_producto" value="{{$detalle->valor_neto}}" readonly /> </td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control total_producto_tabla" id="total_producto" name="total_producto" readonly></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

En el controlador solamente tengo el request actualmente por lo cual no adjunto codigo...

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el atributo "name" del input debes colocarlo como array (name="total_producto[]") y no debes repetir los Id (Buenas practicas).
Ejemplo:

```
 {{index=0}}

    @foreach($detallePedido as $detalle)

        {{index++}};
      <input type="text" class="form-control total_producto_tabla" 
      id={{"total_producto".index}} name="total_producto[]" readonly>

   @endforeach
```

En El controlador:

```
  $total_productos=request->total_producto;
```

/// Ahora $total_productos es un array de esa columna y puedes aplicarle "foreach" a tu criterio.

También hay métodos de array que TE pueden servir para crear una tabla o array bidimensional a partir de columnas, pero un "for" simple uniendo los array's de Tus inputs te servirá.

Comment: Gracias luis, resuelto!!!